# serial port parity

Tags: windows-xp, serial-port

Are there any known problems with using a serial port set for 8 data bits, 1 stop bit and even parity, under Windows XP?

Comment: Not that I know of...although the most common configuration for 8 bits is 8/N/1.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Conventional_notation

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a case of "my code is failing and I really hope there is a problem with Windows XP."  Most likely it's a case of *select is broken* ("this isn't working but it can't possibly be my code").

If you're having problems, post the code and the real issue so we can help you.  You'll also have better luck getting links to specific issues with WinXP and the serial port (I have no idea what issues actually exist).